# Share cloud storage based on filetype

Tags: cloud, google-drive-api, dropbox, google-cloud-storage, onedrive

I've evaluated

- **Google Drive**
- **Dropbox** and
- **OneDrive**

but none can do what I need...

I want to backup our company's files and then **sync** them with certain users, but they must **only have access to specific file-types**

For example I want my graphic designer to have access to all our Photoshop (.psd) files.

Let's say I have files like this:

- `C:\Product1\Product_logo.psd`
- `C:\Product1\Top_secret_dossier.doc`
- `C:\Product2\Product_logo.psd`
- `C:\Product2\Sensitive_Financial_data.xls`

Now I want to share the psd files with my graphic designer.

When I share them with the user this is what they see:

- `Product_logo.psd`
- `Product_logo.psd`

As you can see, the file hierarchy is lost.

Instead I want them to see this:

- `Product1\Product_logo.psd`
- `Product2\Product_logo.psd`

**Is there a cloud storage product that has this kind of control?**

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use gsutil wildcarding to grant permissions within a single bucket for Google Cloud Storage.

`gsutil -m acl ch -g 'GraphicDesigners@yourcompany.com:O' gs://yourbucket/**.psd`

This would grant anyone in the GraphicDesigners group full access to all of the existing psd objects, and the hierarchy would be maintained, while they would not have access to any of the other objects' data.  It's important to note that there's no way to limiting listing permission to only those objects.  If you grant your graphic designers listing permission to the bucket, with:

`gsutil -m acl ch -g 'GraphicDesigners@yourcompany.com:R' gs://yourbucket/`

Then the graphic designers could see that Top_secret_dossier.doc exists (although they wouldn't be able to read any of its data).

If it's important that you conceal even the names of the objects, then you'd need to separate your confidential objects into a different bucket.

Answer (score -1):

GCS supports for [structuring your files using folders](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_creatingfolders), but limitations are
 1. Sharing can be done either at bucket level or at object level
 2. bucket names are universally unique

So sharing limited files will require to keep only those files in the bucket or else specify at object level.

Comment: OK, so you can structure files using folders, just like Google Drive / DropBox / One Drive. 
What's important is to sync all these files with different users, but then restrict what they get to sync/see, such as only PSD files.

Comment: You will need to arrange em in buckets as per your sharing requirement.

Comment: Sharing can be done at the object level too, not just the bucket level.